# sshexec command setup

Tags: ant, ssh

I need to run ant script from a local machine which will invoke ant executions on remote machine.

So on the local ant file I have :

```
<target name="test">
     <sshexec host="${host}" username="${user}"
              password="${pwd}"  trust="yes"
              commandResource="(cd F:\execution; ant -f build.xml run)"/>
</target>
```

On remote machine I have build.xml` which contains

```
<target name="run">
    <mkdir dir ="F:\Testfolder"/>
</target>
```

When I execute the loca ant script I get the following error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (cd F:\execution; ant -f build.xml run) 
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We deploy a build file named "remote-build.xml" to the path `/root/project/remote-build.xml` on the remote machine, and then we use

```
<sshexec host="${host}"
    username="${user}"
    password="${pwd}"
    trust="yes"
    command="ant -f /root/project/remote-build.xml the-targets-to-execute" />
```

to execute the target.

Comment: Thanks coolfan for your reply. I think am missing something in my setup. Both my local and target machine is Windows and i have installed openssh on target machine so that i can do ssh from local machine. But the problem is that coz of openssh it tries to match to linux type folder structure. And i have installed windows type ant over in target machine and when i run program from local am getting error as "cmd : ant -f F:/execution/remote-build.xml run
bash: ant: command not found
Remote command failed with exit status 127". Any idea what i'm missing in setup??

Comment: when i try to do ssh using putty from local machine to target machine i default to /home/copssh/ and when i tired ant -version cmd it throws error as " -bash: ant.bat: command not found"

Comment: Ohhhhh, `bash: ant: command not found` -- this is a PATH problem. The SSH session's PATH is not alsways equal to the System's PATH. You may have Ant installed on that machine with environment varibles set (like ANT_HOME), however the OpenSSH may not use that. You may need to check the documents of your ssh server to see how to add Ant to its PATH.

Comment: That was good guess. Got fixed the Ant installation. Now i execute my code. Btw is there a way to trigger the maven profile of target machine using sshexec command from local machine. i.e.. From local machine the ssheexec command should be something like "mvn install -P run-target" and is this possible?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `sshexec` can execute any command available on the remote machine, as long as you have them in the SSH's PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file in remote machine ( F:\execution\runmanycommands.sh  and execute that file . From the site

> Run a set of commands from a command resource (file) on a remote
>   machine using key authentication with no passphrase

The `commandResource` [expects](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) single resource  file  execute. '(cd F:\execution; ant -f build.xml run)' is not a resource.

(I am not sure your over all goal. Looking at the number questions, I guess you need Continous Integration solution- should check [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) with many of its plugins )

(BTW, you can all ant directly with ant -f , avoiding the need for cd)